# Rails, Postgre - How to sort by association with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting, has-many

How can I sort a list of `Inputs` by the `value` of the `Translation` if one `Input` can have many `Translations`?

```
class Input < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations, dependent: :destroy
end

class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :input
  belongs_to :language
end

# translations table schema:
# id          :integer
# value       :string
# input_id    :integer
# language_id :integer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Input.joins(:translations).order("translations.value DESC")
```

Comment: I understand that approach, but I can't join the translations table because I'm listing the inputs with the translations as columns.
And what translation row that belongs to input is beign sorted if inputs have more than one translation?

Comment: @ViniciusFontoura, You can then `group` the records using any column of `translations` table.